# Help me identify this pin?

Tags: identification, jewelry

Came upon this pin in a box of stuff from my grandfather:

[image: Front of pin]

The back has a little inscription, and a screw-on back that makes it clear this pin is designed to not come off accidentally:

[image: Inscription]
[image: Attachment]

My grandfather moved to Aspen, CO when he was 9 and spent his entire life there.  He was a member of the Fraternal Order of Eagles but this doesn't seem related to that.  I thought "H.S." might be "High School" but he attended Aspen High School.

How can I learn more about this item?

EDITS

- He never worked for General Electric
- [These guys](https://www.ebay.com/itm/VINTAGE-ENAMELED-GOLD-FILLED-G-E-HIGH-SCHOOL-BLUE-RIBBON-FELLOW-SCREW-BACK-PIN-/161575842591) don't know what it is either (that's not my grandfather's pin but it's identical)
- LGB [has been identified](https://community.ebay.com/t5/Collectibles-Art/Help-identifying-lapel-pin/m-p/30439738#M117150) as meaning the pin was produced by the L. G. Balfour company.  Balfour stopped making pins 25+ years ago; their lapel pin line was taken over by Stylecraft USA.  Neither Balfour nor Stylecraft have records that go before 1999.
- "1/10 10K GF" means that it is "Gold Filled":  it's covered with a layer of 10 K gold that constitutes one tenth of the weight of the pin.
- There is a Gardner Edgerton High School in Gardner, KS, and my grandfather was born in White Rock, KS, but the two places are 230 miles apart.  And the school wasn't built until 2000.
- His wife (my grandmother) was Head Nurse at Cincinnati General Hospital in 1919 (in case "H.S." means something like "Health Systems")
- I emailed Classic Medallics, hoping the "M" was their logo, but they replied "Sorry this is not our pin or box"
- I emailed The Academy, they replied "Unfortunately we never handed out pins like that to our health system GE Fellows. We started this program back in 2005 for high potential leaders that are about 1-3 steps away from taking on a c-suite level role (CEO, CFO, COO, CMO, CNO, etc.) at a health system."
- I contacted General Electric and they recommended I email The Museum of Innovation and Science (formerly, the Schenectady Museum Hall of Electrical History) as they have archives of GE company history and photos from the 1880s to the present.  I have done so.

Comment: Maybe "H.S." means "Honor Society" ?

Comment: @justCal Direct link: https://academynet.com/leadership-development/fellowship-programs GE Health Systems fellowships for 'Health System Executives'.

Comment: I've emailed GE, but this seems exceedingly unlikely.  My grandfather definitely was never a C-level executive in any kind of health services company, but we'll see what they come back with!

Comment: His wife had been Head Nurse at Cincinnati General Hospital earlier in her life, but that was in 1919 and as far as I can tell the fellowship on that GE site wasn't created until 2006.  But you raise a good point - maybe it's a memento from another family member ... keep the ideas coming!

Comment: Along with that golden "M", dating the plastic box may help.

Comment: I did a search and found this article. It does mention Kansas, so, perhaps? https://gardnernews.com/lions-club-updates-gehs-wall-in-memory-of-former-member/

Comment: That article also says "when the new Gardner Edgerton High School was built in 2001" so it's possible the old school was around when my grandfather was in Kansas.  It's a long shot but what the heck - I emailed the school secretary!

Comment: What decade was your grandfather in high school? GE could be "General Education" or "General Electric" or "German Exchange" or many things. Someone on Etsy has a pin like this categorized with a bunch of honor society and achievement pins. https://www.etsy.com/listing/791901871/group-of-school-related-awards-medals

Comment: He was born in 1883 so high school would have been right around 1900.  That person on Etsy does have the exact same pin, but from the description I can tell they don't know any more about it than I do (grin)

Comment: Can you give us more on your grandfather's life? Did he go to college? Serve in the military? What did he do for a living and where did he work?

Comment: @BettyCrokker the maker company LGB was founded in 1913, so your granddad was at least 30 when he got the pin, for I don't think a new company can make such a beaut in its early years. It is definitely for some society, not a high school (plus the word fellow is never used for high school affiliation, but mostly for societies). Internet does not help at all!

Can we guess any meaning from the design? Interlocked rings? Like [Vesica piscis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesica_piscis#Uses)

Answer (score 1):

(Too much for a comment, but not a definitive answer)

LGB stands for Lloyd Garfield Balfour, who founded the [L.G. Balfour](https://www.balfour.com/HelpCenter/About-us/About) company in 1913.

One source indicates that LGB was used as a mark in [1944](https://www.costumejewelrycollectors.com/vintage-costume-jewelry-research/costume-jewelry-marks/researching-costume-jewelry-history-jewelry-signatures-b/). Another source indicates that LGB was used [between 1922 and 1963](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-kkk-tri-kappa-skull-fraternity-pin-badge).

Neither the [*International Encyclopedia of Secret Societies and Fraternal Orders*](https://archive.org/details/internationalenc00axel) (Axelrod, 1997) nor the massive [*Encyclopedia of Associations* (52nd ed.)](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9781414468754_1/page/3034/mode/2up) contains any associations with initials G.E.-H.S.

Rather than a two-word "G.E." phrase joined with another two-word "H.S." phrase, this might be a three-word phrase where the middle word is hyphenated, something like Grand English-Hellenic Society.

Choose one from: Grand, Great, Global, General,...
and one from: English, Eastern,...
and one from: Hellenic, Hibernian,...
plus: Society

Comment: @Betty Crokker I googled G.E.H.S. and one result was an eBay listing saying it is a Masonic pin.  But that isn't definitive of course. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Masonic-Pin-Screw-Back-Fellow-G-E-H-S-1-10-10K-Gold-Filled-/114458429407

Comment: Also. how about Graduate Education Health Sciences, did he have any connection with Tulane University?